# Divisible Dates

Tags: calculation-puzzle

The day of the month, and the month of the year, often simultaneously divide the year. Most recently it happened on January 3, 2019 because both 1 (January) and 3 divide 2019.

In our era, since 1/1/1, which years have had the most such dates?

Comment: For clarification: Is a divisible date one in which *either* the day or month divide the year, or one in with *both* do?

Comment: @Van Yes, both.

Comment: can we solve this with some code? :)

Comment: @Flying_whale: Go!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm going to go with

> 1680

factors:

> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,12,14,15,16,20,21,24,28,30

So it hits on

> 179 days (10 months times 18 days, minus 30th of February)

Method:

Looked up

> [Highly composite numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HighlyCompositeNumber.html), picked the largest that's smaller than 2019.

Comment: Van got more days then this, so shouldn’t his be the accepted answer?

Comment: @tyobrien If you look at the bottom right hand corner of the answer, you'll notice that this isn't the [JonMark Perry answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/78854/36023) Van managed to beat. :-)

Answer (score 6):

I found

> with a bit of code i found 1680 with 179 dates you can run it here : https://rextester.com/YITA38880

Answer (score 5):

I believe I can beat JonMark Perry's answer:

> 1260 = 2 x2 x3 x3 x5 x7
>
>  For months, I can get 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, & 12 (10 - same).
>
>  But for days, I get:
>
>  1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 12 & 14, 15, 18, 20, 21, 28, 30 (17 - one more than Jon)

Answer (score 4):

I'd be surprised if you can beat:

> 1080. It equals $2^3\times3^3\times5$, and so covers $1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,12,15,18,20,24,27,30$ for days and $1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,12$ for months.

Answer (score 4):

This is a small enough set that a very simple program should be able to just brute-force it in a fraction of a second. So, [here's a Python version](https://repl.it/repls/StrikingRepulsiveInstitutions). And, just to verify it, [here's a wildly different one)](https://repl.it/repls/MuffledOddballIntelligence).<sup>1</sup>

If you run either one, the winner is:

> 1680, with 179 divisible days.

This makes perfect sense, for the reason [Bass](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/78857/56698) explains, but the brute-forcing shows how you could get the answer even without thinking very far.

That record obviously won't stand forever,<sup>2</sup> but how soon will the record be broken?

Just change the outer loop to `for year in itertools.count(1):` to keep scanning until the end of time,<sup>3</sup> and you'll see that:

> 2520 will have 208 divisible days.

---

<sub>1. Depending on the Python version, the `datetime` type may assume proleptic Georgian, so it'll incorrectly treat 400, 800, and 1200 as leap years. None of those three years is divisible by 29, so it won't make a difference. But better to actually get the rule right, as in the first version, than to get it wrong and then explain why it doesn't matter, right?</sub>

<sub>2. 2329089562800 is a leap year divisible by every number up to 31, so, assuming we use the Gregorian calendar that long, it will have 366 divisible dates.</sub>

<sub>3. Going all the way to 2329089562800 without optimizing the algorithm would probably take a while, but you can hit ^C after you get the first post-2019 record, or after you've seen enough that you're bored.</sub>